# Is an IDE extension an off-site resource, or is does it fall under "software tools commonly used by developers?"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I recently came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69783076/is-there-an-extension-that-allows-the-brackets-code-editor-to-support-bat-files) asking if some extension for an IDE exists that would make it easier to write code in a particular language.

As far as I can tell from [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), the question should be valid because it covers "software tools commonly used by programmers" (the IDE); and is "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" (aka "hey, does this software that I want to use to write code exist?"). Is it a poorly-written question that shows no research? Absolutely; it deserves all the downvotes that it has.

What I'm curious about is whether it was correct for the question to be closed. Surely the IDE itself counts as a tool used by programmers (even if I've never heard of this particular one and it's no longer being developed), but do extensions to that IDE count as part of that IDE (they can't run on their own without it), or are they separate software (since they're separate from the main IDE and submitted by users), which would fall under "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow?"

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Yes, that's my question. Is an extension a tool or software library, or is it part of the IDE?

Comment: @SomethingDark It is, but they're not asking how to use said extension; they're asking us to find or recommend it.

Comment: Asking about how a *particular* extension works, or how to get the extension to do something, is fine. Asking for suggestions for extensions is not.

Comment: The question needs to be a practical problem a developer wants to have solved. Answers might advice on using an extension.

Comment: Well then [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) should be updated to say that questions about _using_ software are okay, because right now it just says that questions about software are okay and that's a _significant_ difference.

Comment: @SomethingDark that same page also says "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic_"

Comment: @SomethingDark It doesn't say that _questions about software are okay_, what it says is _software tools commonly used by programmers; and is_ ... _a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development_ are okay.  Finding an extension for someone or recommending one, is not _software development_, it's using a search engine.  As said by others, it already says that recommendations are off topic; that doesn't leave much wiggle room.

Comment: I would be very curious to see an on-topic question that fits both of those parameters in that case - by that logic, the only acceptable questions about IDEs would be for help in developing IDEs.

Comment: @SomethingDark Using an IDE is how we develop software.

Comment: Yes, but how could anyone ever write a question that was on-topic about it?

Comment: Asking for help using an IDE is on-topic. Asking for a recommendation of which IDE to use is off-topic. Note the "recommendation" part.

Comment: @SomethingDark Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code) and find out; or better yet, search for any IDE's tag on the main site.

Comment: Which brings me back to my original question: is it possible for there to be on-topic questions about IDE extensions (not this question of course, just hypothetically)?

Comment: @SomethingDark As long as those questions are about using that _tool_ for _software development_ ... yes.

Comment: Yes, questions about using or developing IDE extensions are on-topic. Just not questions about *recommending* IDE extensions. I do not understand your confusion. The rule is very simple: recommendation questions are off-topic, regardless of anything else. If you aren't asking for a recommendation, then we evaluate what you are actually asking about to determine whether the question is on-topic.

Comment: I guess I just don't consider "does this exist" to equal "please find this for me" or "please recommend one for me." Also, the [batch-file] tag is notorious for closing pretty much all questions that are low on content as "recommending software" so I think I just assumed that's what happened again.

Comment: @SomethingDark Do you think that the answer "Yes" to the question of "Does this exist?" is alright?

Comment: @Daedalus - If it does exist, yes. "Yes." is a complete sentence, as is "No."

Comment: @SomethingDark It is, but it doesn't meet the minimum character requirement for an answer, despite that fact.  However, for a user asking for the existence of a thing, do you really think they'd be satisfied without a link to said thing, thus making it recommendation?

Comment: @Daedalus - If somebody wants to know where something is, I'd expect them to ask where it is. Knowing how to ask questions correctly is the number one skill a person needs to be a good programmer. Also, if the answer actually is "no" (and I suspect it is for that particular question), they're not going to get a link anyway.

Comment: Uh... I don't think Batch file questions should be getting closed as recommendation questions. Very high odds that's an inappropriate close reason, unless the question is actually asking for something like a recommendation of a Batch file editor/IDE.

Comment: @CodyGray - If you have some free time, you might want to review some of the closed questions on the tag for correct close reason (that said, batch is a dead language and I haven't seen an original question in about 5 years, so in all likelihood there's a dupe out there somewhere that would be the actual correct close reason).

Comment: @SomethingDark I will agree that asking something the proper way is a necessary skill to have; however, this question consists of a single sentence that suggests the OP is looking for an IDE or extension to satisfy their need.  If that is not the case, perhaps someone can ask them to rephrase their question to accurately describe what help they actually need, as long as the above rules are followed.

Comment: @SomethingDark: Batch is not a dead language. CMD.EXE passes quotes (e.g., `"Ninja"` (for the build tool *[Ninja](https://ninja-build.org/manual.html)*)) ***unchanged*** to [CMake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake), whereas PowerShell strips them. This *can* be done with PowerShell, but you end up piping to CMD (if you need to be able to use variables and redirection of standard output - say, for use in a build pipeline) or some other complex solution.

Comment: @PeterMortensen - I meant dead in the sense that Microsoft is no longer adding features to it.

Comment: No longer adding features to something doesn't make it "dead"; it just means it is "complete".

Comment: @CodyGray - I wish this site had a heart reaction for that comment.

Comment: It does; it's shaped like an upward facing triangle. :-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The question is asking for someone to recommend a particular extension. That's a recommendation question, soliciting the recommendation of an off-site resource. The question was correctly closed.

The fact that IDEs and IDE extensions are software tools commonly used by programmers doesn't come into it at all. The question wasn't closed as being off-topic.

Note the bold text on [the Help Center page you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> Some questions that fit into one of the categories listed above may be closed by the community because they aren't generally a good fit here or need additional information:

One of those exceptions is recommendation questions:

> Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.